# In a school the odds of a student speaking spanish are $30\%$.

Tags: probability

If we select $3$ random students, what are the chances of at least one of them speaking spanish?

So, I saw this question and tried to solve it, seemed like an easy question but I was wrong and still not sure why.

Apparently the correct answer is $65.7\%$ ($100\% - 70\% \cdot 70\% \cdot 70\%$).

My first attempt at solving I figured $90\% = 3 \cdot 30\%$ (I just need $1$ student to know spanish, and I have $3$ "chances").

What is the corrent approach for this?

Comment: The "three chances" approach cannot be right. For suppose there were $4$ students. Would the probability of at least one Spanish speaker be $120\%$.

Comment: Was the term "odds" used in the book ? Odds $\neq$ Probability

Answer (score 2):

It is better to think about the complement.  The opposite of selecting at least 1 Spanish speaker is to pick all three students who do NOT speak Spanish.  Can you compute this probability? Then your desired answer is just 100% minus this answer.